# kernel BUG at page_alloc.c

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I know it can be anything,  but what in general does the following kernel message might indicate:

> <2>kernel BUG at page_alloc.c:116!
>
> This architecture does not implement dump_stack()
>
> Kernel panic: Kernel Bug
>
> In interrupt handler - not syncing

<0>Rebooting in 5 seconds..

This happens on a 2.4.20 uclinux-based system (ARM9 MMU-less cpu). Seems like a bad thing has happened during an interrupt handling: faulty RAM, so the kernel could not allocate memory or anything else ?

Would be thankful for any hints.

Comment: I don't know if the ARM9 arch has this - but if you were to enable "FRAME_POINTERS" in the kernel - it might allow it to give you a stack dump.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably check line 116 of `page_alloc.c` in your kernel sources to see what condition triggers this particular BUG message.

Though the fact that you're running on an MMU-less system leads me to suspect that a buggy user process has stomped on part of the kernel's memory.

Answer (score 0):

this clearly looks like an heap or stack corruption, just try to put print in file page_alloc.c, try to print the address of the variable which is accessed before the panic line:116, this will give you some hint if heap or stack corruption has happened.

If you find that its a stack corruption then try to look which variable is declared before the corrupted variable because that might be the culprit variable, this might help you to debug.

If its a heap corruption then its something difficult to debug, then you need find out if some variable allocating less memory but writing more data than allocated bytes.